# Why do constrained types become unconstrained after being used as function parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Person = {
  [P in string]: any;
};
type Student = {
  grade: number;
};
type t0 = Student extends Person ? true : false;
type t1 = (() => Student) extends () => Person ? true : false;
type t2 = ((v: Student) => void) extends (v: Person) => void ? true : false;
```

t0 is true, t1 is true, but t2 is false.

Why is t2 false?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `Student` is stricter than `Person`. Hence,

```
type t2 = ((v: Person) => void) extends (v: Student) => void ? true : false;
```

would return `true`, but

```
type t2 = ((v: Student) => void) extends (v: Person) => void ? true : false;
```

returns `false`

Edit:

To elaborate more, if you have an object:

```
const student: Student = {
  grade: 5
}
```

you can say that this student is also a `Person`, since `number` (grade) extends `any`, and `grade` satisfies `[P in string]`. Typescript shows `true` - `Student` extends `Person`.

`t1` from your example returns a `Student`. Any function that returns a `Student` can be claimed to return a `Person` (based on the explanation above).

`t2` is different because you *accept* a parameter of a `Student`. If a function accepts a `Student`, it doesn't necessarily accept a `Person`. So if you flip it - it will work (a function accepting a `Person` will definitely accept a more stricter `Student`), but not vice versa

Comment: It might also be useful to link to [the documentation for `--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) which explains why functions are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in their parameter types